# Execute docker commands in jenkins (in docker container)

Tags: shell, docker, jenkins

With docker compose i launch a jenkins container and i want to have the possibility to execute docker command with(docker installed on the server).

But when i tried to make a simple test run hello-world image i have the following error :

`docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?.`

I set the user on the docker group, what's wrong with my docker compose file ?
in other post i see if i add this line :

```
/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

my container with jenkins can communicate with docker

**my docker compose file**

```
jenkins:
    image: jenkins:2.32.3
    ports:
    - 8088:8080
    - 50000:50000

    volumes:
    - /home/my-user-name/docker-jenkins/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    - /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker
    - /tmp:/tmp
```

Answer (score 2):

To access the docker.sock file, you must run with a user that has filesystem access to read and write to this socket. By default that's with the root user and/or the docker group on the host system.

When you mount this file into the container, that mount keeps the same uid/gid permissions on the file, but those id's may map to different users inside your container. Therefore, you should create a group inside the container as part of your Dockerfile that maps to the same gid that exists on the host, and assign your jenkins user to this group, so that it has access to the docker.sock. Here's an example from a Dockerfile where I do this:

```
...
ARG DOCKER_GID=993
RUN groupadd -g ${DOCKER_GID} docker \
 && useradd -m -d /home/jenkins -s /bin/sh jenkins \
 && usermod -aG docker jenkins
...
```

In the above example, 993 is the docker gid on my host.